# sorting a tcl array according to a value in the key

Tags: arrays, tcl

I noticed a lot of examples here how to sort an array with 1 value per each key, question is: how can I sort an array with an elaborated value?
e.g.

```
set a(one) "some sort of text and num 234"
set a(two) "same format of text with 123"
set a(three) "same format of text with 12.3"
```

How can I sort according to the number at the end of the value?
Currently I'm pushing the text to a file and sorts it using `sort`, but this is ugly and cumbersome.
My end goal is to print the sorted array into a file.

Comment: Given the above, what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the -stride flag of `lsort` is useless here, solved it with a list of lists:

```
 foreach {k v} [array get paths] {                                                                                                                               
   lappend xx [concat $k $v]                                                                                                                         
 } 
 lsort  -index 11 $xx
```

Can reconstruct the array later on (I remained with the list of lists)

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to turn the array into a list, then sort that list:

```
set a(one) "some sort of text and num 234"
set a(two) "same format of text with 123"
set a(three) "same format of text with 72.3"

parray a

# Convert array into list of {number key value} then sort
set aList {}
foreach {key value} [array get a] {
    lappend aList [list $key $value]
}
# aList now is {
#     {one "some sort of text and num 234"}
#     {two "same format of text with 123"}
#     {three "same format of text with 72.3"}
# }

# Sort and print
# The -index {1 end} tells lsort to first pick index 1 (the value)
# then pick index "end" (last index) of the value, which is the
# number. Finally, the -real flag tells lsort to sort by real numbers,
# not by text value.
puts "---"
foreach sublist [lsort -index {1 end} -real $aList] {
    lassign $sublist key value
    puts "$key: $value"
}
```

Output:

```
a(one)   = some sort of text and num 234
a(three) = same format of text with 72.3
a(two)   = same format of text with 123
---
three: same format of text with 72.3
two: same format of text with 123
one: some sort of text and num 234
```

Answer (score 0):

We can store the array in a dict, and use lsort on that:

```
proc last_word_sort {a b} {
    set last_a [lindex [split $a] end]
    set last_b [lindex [split $b] end]
    if {$last_a < $last_b} then {return -1}
    if {$last_a > $last_b} then {return +1}
    return 0
} 

set a(one) "some sort of text and num 234"
set a(two) "same format of text with 123"
set a(three) "same format of text with 12.3"

set b [dict create {*}[array get a]]

foreach {key value} [lsort -stride 2 -index 1 -command last_word_sort $b] {
    puts "$key => $value"
}
```

```
three => same format of text with 12.3
two => same format of text with 123
one => some sort of text and num 234
```